# message google apps script UrlFetchApp + vk API

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, google-apps-script

Подскажите как отправить через google apps script сообщение в чат вк от лица сообщества?
Сообщение из простого текста, искомые данные - таблица google sheets
Что нужно получить от вк чтобы это работало и какой минимальный код потребуется для отправки сообщения?
пример того что я смог собрать, но не работает почему то, максимум чего добился - это ответа от сервера "200"

```
    function newMessage()
    {
       var access_token = '***';
       var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/messages.send?uid=59142418&message=ХабраХабр&title=Заголовок&access_token="+ access_token +"&v=5.131");
       Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Тут Вам больше с ВК Апи нужно разобраться. Какие запросы в каком виде принимает. И что отправляет обратно. Итд итп